# Tools or Workflow to Copy 1000s of features into another feature class without Copy+Paste

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, copy

I have 2055 features I need to copy to another feature class.  I created the new feature class with new fields and field order, so it's not a simple "export data" solution.  If I select all 2055 features and copy while in edit mode, the "paste" option disappears.  There appears to be a limit of ~100 features for copy+paste workflow in edit.  So...are there tools I can use to more efficiently move the data into the new feature class?

I am not a Python user, so if you have a Python script to offer, please give instructions "for dummies" on how to input/run it.

Comment: I haven't tried it in about a year, but did copy/paste thousands of features from a layer to another in 10.x. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the brief [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. As people post questions here in the comments section, please [edit] your question to clarify it based on commenters' questions. Does your target feature class already have features in it that you need to retain? Would you be open to a solution that creates a new feature class by itself?

Comment: You could also use the built in Append tool in No Test mode,  you would need to manually map your fields from the old feature class to the new one if any of the field names are different.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Catalog window in ArcMap, navigate to your newly created feature class then right click on it and choose "Load/Load data..." (or something similar, my version of ArcGis is not in English). You will access a wizard that let you choose witch data to load (don't forget to click the add button after selecting the data), selecting a subset of the data if you need to, and has a field mapping option to match the fields if you rename some of them.

This tool shouldn't have any problem to load 1000 record (or much more than that...)

If you want to create the new feature class during export there is the "[Feature class to feature class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm)" tool that let you add, delete, rename and order field